# Group signature without anonymity of the members

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, digital-signature, signature, anonymity

I'm looking for a crypto digital signature algorithm with the same properties as a group/ring-signature (you can always determine that the signer belong to a specific set), but without the anonymity of the signer.

In other words I'm looking for an algorithm where I can always find the identity of the signer and I also want to prove his belonging to a specific group.

Does such algorithm exists? Or is there any way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect question for [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), not so good for stackoverflow.

Comment: How are you planning to maintain the membership of the group?